# Got TLS error while trying to find package flutter_lints at https://pub.dev - Exit code 69 in Flutter application

Tags: flutter

When we created flutter application, then it gave the Got TLS error trying to find package flutter_lints at https://pub.dev.
exit code 69.

I need to fix this error. Need help for this.

I already follow these instructions, but couldn't fi it.
([link](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/help))

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDWoW.jpg)